# Eclipse moonrise theme removing white scope selection

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I started using Eclipse's moonrise theme but I noticed that whenever I click on a particular line, the scope of the method the line is in is indicated by the white bar on the left (convering lines 127-129 as you can see in the image). Is there a way to edit its color (change it to something less conspicuous maybe)? It gets slightly distracting when I'm moving between methods and the white bar keeps changing size.

[image]

Comment: I believe it comes with the theme. You should locate the css file for this theme and edit.

Comment: What do I edit in the css file?